# How can I replace a file in Winrar and keep the compression ratio?

Tags: zip

For example, I have a file A.bin with a ratio of 50%, how can I replace it with a similar A.bin (exact same size) from outside and keep exactly the ratio of 50%?

Answer (score 0):

The compression ratio is defined as the size of the compressed file over the original file. Unfortunately, it is not always possible to achieve a given compression ratio for a certain file.

A good, tangible, example of this might be text versus images: compressing repetitive text like log files is a very easy problem and will typically yield a great compression ratio even with fairly relaxed compression levels whereas an image of static noise is very random data and therefore can be very hard to compress.

All this is to say that the compression ratio you achieve is highly dependent on what the data is and the algorithm used to compress it, it is not necessarily an easily tuneable factor. If by changing the file you add more 'randomness' to the data, it will not be possible to get a better compression ratio.

Now, if the compressed sizes of your files are same it should be possible to replace into the archive but as you can see getting two compressed files to have the same size is non-trivial.

If you can reliably guarantee that your transformation to the file decreases entropy then you might be able to guarantee that the compressed file will be smaller and add padding null bytes to keep the size of the compressed data the same (artificially increase the compression ratio).